# Arrows tutorial teaser

Tags: haskell, arrows

I can't understand the code from the [teaser in the HaskellWiki arrows tutorial](https://wiki.haskell.org/Arrow_tutorial#A_Teaser):

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let
        prepend x = arr (x ++)
        append  x = arr (++ x)
        withId  t = returnA <+> t
        xform = (withId $ prepend "<") >>>
                (withId $ append ">") >>>
                (withId $ ((prepend "!") >>> (append "!")))
        xs = ["test", "foobar"] >>= (runKleisli xform)
    mapM_ putStrLn xs
```

where

```
   (withId f) >>> (withId g) =
   (returnA <+> f) >>> (returnA <+> g) =
   ((arr id) <+> f) >>> ((arr id) <+> g)
```

and

```
   ((id . id) x) ++ ((id . f) x) ++ ((id . g) x) ++ ((g . f) x) =
   x ++ (f x) ++ (g x) ++ ((g . f) x)
```

In the last two lines I can't figure out where exactly the distributive proprieties of composition (.) come from

Comment: `id . x = x = x . id`

Comment: I think the last `((id . g) x)` in the teaser is correct but misleading, it should read `((g . id) x)`.

Comment: Also keep in mind that by `(g . f)` the teaser means multivalued composition, which differs from plain Haskell composition operator `(.)`. Multivalued composition is something like `\x -> f x >>= g` or `concatMap g . f`. This surely does not help understanding it.